# Update an admin_date field across multiple feature classes in the same database

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes

I am putting together a database focused on land management and to track changes would like to have an admin_date field populated in each of the feature classes in the database with the same date.

Is there is a quick way to automate that using ArcGIS Pro, or how would I go about that in the most efficient way possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use modelbuilder and a featureclass iterator to loop through the feature classes in your geodatabase. Then simply feed that into an add field and a calculate field tool. Total build time <1 minute.